# Swift different array behaviour with 'import Foundation'

Tags: arrays, swift, foundation

When I run the following code I get the expected output:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a

if a === b { println("a === b") }
if a == b { println("a == b") }
```

Output:

> a === b
>
> a == b

However, if I import Foundation suddenly I only a new output:

```
import Foundation    

var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a

if a === b { println("a === b") }
if a == b { println("a == b") }
```

Output:

> a == b

Does anyone know what is going on behind the scenes? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with mutability, though the `import Foundation` part is interesting. My guess is that it has to do with `NSArray` or `NSObject` copying.

You can test it by changing your `var` to `let` and watching `===` become true again.

Test the different permutations and see what happens:

### Both Mutable

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a

if a === b { println("arrays are the same instance") }  // false
if a == b { println("arrays are equivalent") }  // true
```

### Mutable Source, Immutable Copy

```
var a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = a

if a === b { println("arrays are the same instance") }  // false
if a == b { println("arrays are equivalent") }  // true
```

### Immutable Source, Mutable Copy

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a

if a === b { println("arrays are the same instance") }  // false
if a == b { println("arrays are equivalent") }  // true
```

### Both Immutable

```
let a = [1, 2, 3]
let b = a

if a === b { println("arrays are the same instance") }  // true
if a == b { println("arrays are equivalent") }  // true
```

This is actually the proper behavior for making a defensive copy, only when necessary.

If your source is mutable, you have to make a copy otherwise changes could be made externally. If you want a mutable copy you need to make a copy of course.

The only time a copy is not made is when both the source and copy are immutable, because that would be wasteful.

Comment: Yes this does appear to be the case... It's very interesting but I was more interested in what the Foundation import does to activate this behaviour.

Comment: Probably since it imports `Foundation.NSArray`, which handles the backing store for these types.